# Added a scss file, compass does not generate css?

Tags: compass-sass, compass, susy-sass

I've added a new .scss file to my components directory in Zen.  Compass sees the file, because I get the message 'file modified' but I do not get a .css file generated

I'm new to compass and sass.  Do I need to map files somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.  I needed to include the new scss in my styles.scss file.